# Multipath TCP packet out-of-order

Tags: networking, mptcp

I heard that packet reordering problem is major reason to reduce performance

Packet out-of-order problem is more serious when sub-flows latency is severely different.

But when I see MPTCP with uncoupled congestion control, performance doesn't decrease. When I using uncoupled congestion control, out-of-order doesn't reduce the performance?

Comment: TCP infer loss events by counting duplicate acks, which is why packet reordering reduce performance. An effort called RACK aims at increasing performance in environments with high reordering degree. It makes use of timers instead of duplicate acks. RACK will allow for more parallelism in HW and thus more capacity. I have limited knowledge about MPTCP, hopefully someone else can answer

Answer (score 0):

uncoupled congestion control doesn't relax the constraints about in-order MPTCP level problems: once segments arrive at the receiver, they must be sent to the application in-order. Maybe you see less of a difference because you get more bandwidth as uncoupled is more aggressive.